# Pattern guards and lets

Tags: haskell

While working through the first couple exercises of project euler I was surprised by the way haskell handles failed let bindings within do notation.
I intended to do the equivalent of:

```
sundays = length $ do
  year <- [1901..2000]
  month <- [1..12]
  (_, _, 7) <- return . toWeekDate $ fromGregorian year month 1
  return ()
```

That is, check how often the first day of the month within a certain time range is a Sunday. This works and doing this with a case binding works as well. The let binding which seems like it ought to do the same thing always passes, though:

```
sundays = length $ do
  year <- [1901..2000]
  month <- [1..12]
  let (_, _, 7) = toWeekDate $ fromGregorian year month 1
  return ()
```

What causes this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `let` binding in your second example is never evaluated because its value is never used. It is the same as writing:

```hs
sundays = length $ do
  year <- [1901..2000]
  month <- [1..12]
  return ()
```

If you wanted to expand the second example, I'd suggest using [`guard`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:guard) from `Control.Monad`, which will effectively filter the results as expected:

```hs
sundays2 = length $ do
  year <- [1901..2000]
  month <- [1..12]
  let (_, _, day) = toWeekDate $ fromGregorian year month 1
  guard $ day == 7
  return ()
```

`guard` is what is used behind the scenes in list comprehension. Your code above could be written in list comprehension form like this:

```hs
sundays3 = length $ [ () | year <- [1901..2000]
                         , month <- [1..12]
                         , let (_, _, day) = toWeekDate $ fromGregorian year month 1
                         , day == 7 ]
```

Comment: Oh, and binding with `<-` desugars into a case statement with mfail as default branch, for lists the same as guard. That also clears up some misconceptions I had about how let bindings in do notation desugar, thanks!